# Колонка checkbox в таблице для массовых действий в Yii2

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, ооп

На сайте я делаю выборку из БД и вывожу данные в виде таблице, но мне также надо напротив каждой строки иметь input checkbox для того, чтобы отмечать определенные строки и по нажатию кнопки удалять/редактировать строки. Как это грамотно реализовать в Yii2?
На данный момент часть view c таблицей выглядит так:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'files-form']); ?>
...
...
<?php foreach($files as $k=>$v): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $form->field($model, 'checkbox[]')->checkbox(['value'=>$v->id])->label(false);?> </td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

При отправке такой "формы" в контроллере ловится $model->checkbox в виде огромного массива с кучей нулевых значений и только в отмеченных строках значение отличается от нуля и является тем, что передается в строке 'value'=>$v->id
Получается можно оперировать этим огромным массивом, но является ли такой способ правильным и как при такой реализации сделать в шапке таблице один чекбокс, при отметке которого он делает отмеченными все чекбоксы в таблице? Или же есть другой способ решить эту задачу?

Comment: Есть вариант сделать вашу таблицу через стандартный GridView ( https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview ), и использовать в нем CheckboxColumn ( https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn )

Comment: Как вариант реализовать это все на клиенте, при клике на элемент класть его id в массив и на нажатие кнопки вешать отправку запроса на сервер со списком id'шников.